# Unable to load document at run-time from Project\Data Folder in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xml

I'm trying to load an XML document which is in Project\Data as shown below:

```
            XmlDocument memoryDoc = new XmlDocument();
            memoryDoc.Load(@"Data/Memories.xml");
            XmlNode xmlNode_Memories = memoryDoc.SelectSingleNode("Memories");
            XmlElement xmlElement_Memory = memoryDoc.CreateElement("Memory");
            xmlElement_Memory.SetAttributeNode("Title", "");
            xmlElement_Memory.SetAttribute("Title", "hijdnjh9d2qhei");
            xmlNode_Memories.AppendChild(xmlElement_Memory);
            memoryDoc.Save(@"Data/Memories.xml");
```

but the program is trying to load it from Project\bin\Debug\Data, which doesn't exist, and it cries. How do I get it to load from Project\Data without having to include the full path, even if just for testing purposes?

Also would this cause problems when packaging my program in an installer, and therefore require me to copy the file to a different location before loading?

Comment: Are you running in Release or Debug mode? Do you have a folder called Data in the bin\Release or bin\Debug folder? If you reference a relative path you must have the Data folder with the xml file in the same folder where your executable is.

Comment: Is the Memories.xml file present under bin directory after you have compiled the application? You might have to set the Build Action to "Embed Resources" and Copy to output directory to "Copy Always" for Memroies.xml file.

Comment: @Tudor I'm currently running in Debug mode. So, if I was to install this program and then run it, I'd need to make sure that any relative paths that I reference start from the same folder as the executable?

Comment: @duney, yes, that is correct.

Comment: @PawanMishra Where do I access this setting? Thanks.

Comment: Right click on the file and select properties. In the properties explorer window, you can find these options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is happening because your exe is running from the Project\bin\debug directory (that's where your build output goes when you press F5/Run/Debug in Visual Studio, assuming you are doing a debug build.

If you want to avoid a hard coded path, you could use a post build event to copy the file to the Project\bin\debug\data directory.

Right-click on the project in Solution explorer and choose properties.  Go to the Build Events tab.  It's kind of like writing a batch file, you can copy the file from there.  (click "edit", and then press the Macros button -- there are expansion variables that provide your paths)

The command would look something like (from memory, so might be a little off):

```
copy $(ProjectDir)\Data\Memories.xml $(TargetDir)\data\.
```